# How do i get record by id in php

Tags: php

Here is my database view

[image]

I need to get title by using student id 232. But student id is stored in array like 192,229,232. How can i retrive 232 records only?

Please guide me..

Thanks

Comment: You need to learn about [Database normalisation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm)

Answer (score 2):

you use `IN` clause for get record from array

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * 
          FROM `table` 
         WHERE `id` IN (' . implode(',', array_map('232', $array)) . ')';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)

Eg.

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE FIND_IN_SET(232,student);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE` condition to fetch results that contain this `student` id:

```
SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE student LIKE '%232%';
```

This will return you all rows that contain '232' in `student` column.

But if you have an opportunity to change your table structure I would suggest you to extract `student` column to a pivot table.

You could create `event_student` table that would contain just two columns: `event` and `student`. And each row would link particular `student` to a particular `event`. The data could be easily extracted with a simple JOIN:

```
SELECT * FROM `event` e
    INNER JOIN `event_student` es ON e.eventID=es.event
    WHERE es.student=232;
```

If you store connections between student and events this way you will gain flexibility in your queries and avoid possible mistakes that may occur when using the answer suggested above. Imagine that you have a student with id 2324 or 12323. Both of them contain desired '232' string and both  will match the `'%232%'` pattern and lead to returning you wrong data.